# Formation of quadratic equation using roots

Tags: quadratics

If $a$ and $b$ are the roots of the equation $x^2-px+q=0$, then find the quadratic equation the roots of which are $(a^2-b^2)(a^3-b^3)$ and $a^3b^2+a^2b^3$.

**My Try** So I tried to write the roots in the form of sum and products of roots of the given equation. The only doubt that I have is, I can convert every term to the sum and product of roots form ( in terms of $p$ and $q$), but I have no idea how to do the same for the term $(a^2-b^2)$.

*If there is another better way to solve this problem, let me know. Thanks for devoting this your time*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints: $ab=q$, $a+b=p$, $$a^3b^2+a^2b^3=(ab)^2(a+b),$$ $$(a^2-b^2)(a^3-b^3)=(a+b)(a-b)^2((a+b)^2-ab),$$ and $$(a-b)^2 = (a+b)^2-4ab.$$

Comment: It's not $(a-b)^2$ it's $(a^2-b^2)$.

Comment: $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: Yea that's what I thought. Thanks I'll just give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I got it. Actually, you know what's better? $(a^3-b^3)$ is actually $(a-b)(a^2+b^2+ab)$.This solves the problem straight away!. But thanks for your time and effort anyway!

Comment: @user38227 $a-b$ is antisymmetric in the roots (changes sign when you switch the roots), but you get one factor from $a^2-b^2$ and another from $a^3-b^3$ and $(a-b)^2$ is symmetric (because$ (-1)^2=1$).

Comment: @Mark Bennet, that's true, I solved it.